# Почему метод filter не фильтрует 0?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

Есть такой код:

```
function filter_list(arr) {
    return arr.filter(item => {
        if (typeof (item) == 'number') return item; // [1, 2]
    }) 
}
console.log(filter_list([1, 2, 0, 'a', 'b']));
```

Метод `filter` пропускает `0`, даже если написать так:

```
|| item == 0
```

Comment: А что 0 это не number?

Comment: потому что в `filter` в случае `item === 0` выражение `return item` будет интерпретировано как `return false`

Comment: Тогда как мне его выводить, через map?

Comment: `arr.filter(item => typeof item === 'number')`

Answer (score 7):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> callback
>
> Функция, которая будет вызвана для каждого элемента массива.
> Если функция возвращает true, то элемент остаётся в массиве, если
> false, то удаляется.

В `filter` в случае когда `item === 0` выражение `return item` будет интерпретировано как `return false`.

Нужно написать так:

```js
function filter_list_like_in_question(arr) {
  return arr.filter((item) => {
    if (typeof(item) === 'number') {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

function filter_list(arr) {
  return arr.filter(item => typeof(item) === 'number')
}

console.log(filter_list_like_in_question([1, 2, 0, 'a', 'b']));
console.log(filter_list([1, 2, 0, 'a', 'b']));
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам не нужно делать `return` explicitly, в противном случае, при варианте нуля он будет интерпретирован как `false`.

Достаточно сформировать условие при котором элементы будут оставлены в массиве:

```js
function filter_list(arr) {
  return arr.filter(item => typeof item === "number")
}

const result = filter_list([1, 2, 0, -1, "a", "b"])

console.log(result)
// [1, 2, 0, -1]
```

Comment: а если в массиве отрицательные числа будут?

Comment: Простите, но в первом случае для массива `[1, 2, 0, -1, "a", "b", '', 'j', true, false, NaN, undefined]` будет результат  `[1, 2, 0, -1, "", true, false]`

Comment: @azlov, да Вы правы, в задаче тах условий конечно не было, но тогда остается только один короткий вариант под номером два, через typeof